# Value out of NSDictionary is valid, inside is null

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdictionary

I have a problem absurd.

I have the values ​​of different type, which insert in a dictionary. The problem is that the value out of the dictionary is valid, inside is null.

```
 NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_nameTextField.text];
 NSString *icon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",itemIcon];

 NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:name,@"name",
icon,@"icon", nil];

NSLog(@"string %@ dictionary %@",icon,[dictionary objectForKey:@"icon"]);
```

LOG

```
string 18 dictionary (null)
```

This problem only occurs on the second value, the first "name" does not. Yet the process is the same.

What is more strange, this piece of code, I am using in another class, identical and it works well.

Now I wonder. Can be a problem in Xcode?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is `itemIcon`? And can you try to print the dictionary in NSLog and post that.

Comment: Please provide a complete example. Best guess is that dictionary is not being created because the name (or possibly item) is bad.

Comment: Please don't misuse `stringWithFormat:`. The 1st line should be: `NSString *name = _nameTextField.text;`.

Comment: Log `dictionary`. If `name` is `nil`, nothing will be added to the dictionary.

Comment: I found the problem maybe. To simplify the question, I have included only two values ​​in the dictionary (are 6 values). In reality I noticed that a specific value invalidates those later.

The value in question is an entity of Core-Data. If this is null, even after those are null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create a dictionary using `initWithObjectsAndKeys` (or `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:`), a `nil` value indicates the end of the arguments.

This is true whether you enter an explicit `nil` in the argument list (like everyone does at the end), or if any variable with a `nil` value is used.

```
NSSString *name = nil;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:name, @"name", nil];
```

This gives you an empty dictionary because the first argument is `nil`. None of the other arguments are even looked at.